# Designing a Li-ion charge-discharge controller circuit

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, lithium-ion, bms

I have an interview test task to design a device that contains several sensors of different purpose and a heater.

The problem is that the device has to be portable, so I calculated the required Li-ion battery parameters (5 in series, up to 10 A), but the biggest struggle is to design a battery management system.

It seems like internet is obsessed with implementing it as a module, and I don't think that it is apropriate to implement a module to an interview design lol :)

I have a week for completion but I am kind of lost. I hope passing it in time since designing a BMS is quite knowledge-intensive and this is very new to me. Where should I start my research?

Comment: Read this first https://www.synopsys.com/glossary/what-is-a-battery-management-system.htmland  and this https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/introduction-to-battery-management-systems/

Comment: Why wouldn't it be appropriate to use a BMS module? The main objective of your task seems to be related to sensors and actuators, not to battery management. So I would simply use an existing module as part of your design.